# Loop for xml.documentElement

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I would like to display 8 men et 2 women in svg.
Actually my function display only 1 man and 1 woman
How to insert this loop ?

```
  for (i = 0; i < Serie[n].Number; i++) {
return xml.documentElement
  }
```

My Array is

```
Serie[{Genre:"Man", Number:"8"},{Genre:"Woman", Number:"2"}]
```

My function is :

```
  var PictoContainer = d3.select("html").select("#container2")

   for (n = 0; n < Serie.length; n++) { 

    d3.xml("svg/"+ Serie[n].Genre +".svg","image/svg+xml", function(xml) {

     PictoContainer
        .append("table")
        .append("tr")
        .append("td")
        .append(function(d) {
        return xml.documentElement
                      }) 

     d3.selectAll("svg")
        .attr("opacity", 0.6)
        .attr("width", 23)
        .attr("height", 50)

                })   
        }
```

Comment: You don't need a loop. Use D3's data binding, see e.g. [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (n = 0; n < Serie.length; n++) {  // just like you did
  for (var m = 0; m < Serie[n].Number ; m++) { // add this!
    <your d3.xml code comes here>
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks it's work but I'd like to display 8 men in same line and 2 woman in second line.